# Remove Authorization header in 307 redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I'm making a request to a same-origin API with Angular. That request returns a `307` code with a pre-signed url to Amazon S3.

The request to Amazon fails because it contains the Authorization header I sent to my API in the initial request, and it should't be there. I need to be able to remove it after my API returns the 307 but before the request to Amazon is made.

From what I've gathered, the browser follows that redirect automatically and there is no way to intercept it. Also, Angular doesn't even realize it's a redirect, it's all handled by the XMLHTTPRequest object.

I know XMLHTTPRequest has the withCredentials parameter which:

`Is a Boolean that indicates whether or not cross-site Access-Control requests should be made using credentials such as cookies or authorization headers.`

It's in `false` but the authorization header is still sent across all requests.

I know with other http libraries this would be possible, but not sure it there's any workaround for the browser.

Comment: With XMLHTTPRequest you can’t — see https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-same-origin: *“The withCredentials attribute has no effect when fetching same-origin resources.”* But if instead of XMLHTTPRequest, you use the fetch API, it won’t send credentials for same-origin fetches unless you explicitly tell it to. (XMLHTTPRequest is a legacy API at this point; for new code, it’s better to use the fetch API, which is supported in all modern browsers https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch.)

Comment: Yeah but as usual, it's not supported in IE and for my application it's a requirement to work across all browsers. Also the problem here is I must send the credentials to my same-origin request, but not for the cross-origin one. I find it odd that's not the default for XMLHTTPRequest or any other client. Thanks for you comment anyway.

Comment: Did you find a solution for the redirected S3 upload problem?

Comment: Hey, I just ended up modifying the API so that it doesn't return a 307 code but a 200 with the new link to follow, and then following that link manually.

Comment: I've encountered the same issue. Tested with redirect 302,303 and 307. Setting CORS headers (`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false`) on the redirect response has no effect either. I find it strange that access tokens are apparently just sent to a completely different domain on redirect, could this not be a security issue?

Comment: @sgdesmet I agree, it looks like a security issue. So I guess we'll have to wait till the fetch API becomes more popular and XMLHTTPRequest becomes deprecated? Seems odd anyway.